# Devise - sign_in() not working rails 5.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Created new ruby app

in my controller im trying to sign in a user like so

```
    email = params[:email]
    password = params[:password]

    user = User.authenticate(email, password)

    if user 
        sign_in(user)

        redirect_to root_path
    else

        render json: {success: false}
    end
```

The user is going into sign_in

console is printing:

```
Processing by AccountController#sign_in_user as */*
  Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"email@live.com", "subdomain"=>"app"}
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "email@live.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:9
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/account_controller.rb:11
Redirected to http://app.lvh.me:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

It then redirects to my root path for authenticated users and gives me a 401

```
    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-30 21:53:39 -0400
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"app"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In the DB the user's current_sign_in, last_sign_in, ect.. are being updated

I've done this numerous times, i'm not sure why its not working, any ideas?

Comment: I assume you did run `rails g devise:install` and configured your routes correctly? What other controller actions might be at play here?  Anything related in `application_controller.rb` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder i ended up having an extra line with '  devise_for :users' in my routes that was causing this issue, i'm surprised it didn't break the app... literally had me going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Well after an hour of going crazy

i had a random line in my routes

```
  devise_for :users
```

with no end doing nothing and it was causing this issue.

after removing that everything is fine.